Finite element method approximation

In the picture above, we have on the left a figure representing spatial element, and on the right a figure representing reference element.
The type of element used in the method here is a linear quadrilateral element.
What I understand is moving or mapping from the reference element domain $\Omega^R$ where it seems that the quadrilateral element looks square; I don't understand why it is a square, to the spatial element domain $\Omega^e$, we use with such mapping the basis functions.
I think the basis functions $N$ is what is giving us the quadrilateral shape?
For approximating spatial coordinates, $x_i$ at $\Omega^e$ is approximated by the summation over the nodal values $x_i^k$, (here $k$ symbolizes node and $i$ symbolizes direction), I'm not sure  if $x_i$ will be the average coordinate of the individual element since we're summing over the coordinates of each node.
Clarification is appreciated. Thank you.

I think natural coordinates ($\xi$ and $\eta$ here) are used to simplify some calculations and definitions. For example, base functions are defined by simpler expressions in these coordinates.

@TomášLétal Thank you for your comment. When we sum over the nodal values, do we get the average value of the element?

I don't think so, because generally, you need to do a weighted sum. In this regard, natural coordinates may be a bit misleading.

For the reference element, you got it backwards. You can map any shape to any other shape with the same topology (and some niceness on boundaries and stuff, but let's not get into that). The "geometric" element is mapped to a square element because we choose to. Mainly because this simplifies integration.
The $N$ functions are chosen (or calculated) in order to get this mapping. The usual choice is Lagrange polynomials, written in the reference element.
As for your second question, it depends on how you define "average". If by that you mean a weighted average, then yes. The easiest way to see this is by choosing a corner of the reference element, say $(\xi,\eta)=(-1,-1)^{T}$
The weighted average here would be, for the $x$ coordinate,
$$
x_i=1\cdot x_1+0\cdot x_2+0\cdot x_3+0\cdot x_4
$$
few people would call that an average, but it's just a matter of definition.

Thank you. So, the shape or basis functions $N$ are multiplied in order to do the mapping and to change the shape? And as for the sum, the sum gives a vector $x$ (that depends on the parameters from the reference element) containing two components on x and y axis. Now this vector seems to represent one point only since it has only one component along x axis and one component along y axis. So this point represents the average for the whole element? And it is derived using information from the nodes themselves,so by other words,the position of the element is approximated using nodes information?

Sorry I meant "weighted average" as you described it well.

Almost. What the sum actually does is map (uniquely, except in degenerate elements) any point (\xi,\eta) in the reference element to a point (x,y) in the actual element.

Thanks. In addition to mapping, does it also do interpolation using the information given at the nodal points?

Yes. You use the same idea to interpolate values inside the geometric element.
